# maven 3.3 support for Websphere 8.5.5 - pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, websphere, pom.xml, websphere-8

I could not find a way to deploy my war file in websphere 8.5.5 using maven's pom.xml.
I see there is a plugin called was6-maven-plugin-1.2.1. and it can support WAS 6+, 7+, 8+ as well it seems.

But i could not deploy a war file using this plugin. It throws the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:was6-maven-plugin:1.2.1:installApp (default-cli) on project TEST: Bad archive: C:\test.war -> [Help 1]
```

Please comment on...

My pom.xml configuration FYR:

```
            <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>was6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>integration-test</id>
              <phase>integration-test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>installApp</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <wasHome>C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer</wasHome>
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>
            <server>server1</server>
            <node>localhostNode01</node>
            <virtualHost>default_host</virtualHost>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <conntype>SOAP</conntype>
            <port>8880</port>
            <earFile>test.war</earFile>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <updateExisting>true</updateExisting>
            <applicationName>${project.build.finalName}</applicationName>                           
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For developing project for WebSphere using Maven, follow this document [Setting up your environment for Maven](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/setenv.htm?lang=en) to configure environment.

Especially for WAS 8.5.5 you should use the following entry in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
      <artifactId>was</artifactId>
      <version>8.5.5</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

For this POM target, you are required to use launch configuration scripts that copy runtime libraries to the local Maven repository.

See the [Configuring dependency POM files that emulate the classpath of specific WebSphere runtime environments](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/localrepo.htm?lang=en) for detailed instructions how to copy these libraries.

Comment: Thank you Gas. It is useful.